# Separate string by whitespace, but keep newlines in split array

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I'm trying to split a string in Java, but keep the newline characters *as elements in the array*.

For example, with input: `"Hello \n\n\nworld!"`

I want the output to be: `["Hello", "\n", "\n", "\n", "world", "!"]`

The regex I have in place right now is this:
`String[] parsed = input.split(" +|(?=\\p{Punct})|(?<=\\p{Punct})");`

This gets me the punctuation separation I want, but its output looks like this:
`["Hello", "\n\n\nworld", "!"]`

Is there a way to unclump the newlines in Java?

Comment: Use the find method instead of split. It's easier to define the items you want, than fighting against lookarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first replace all `\n` with `\n` (newline and a space) and then do a simple split on the space character.

```
    String input = "Hello \n\n\nworld!";
    String replacement = input.replace("\n", "\n ");
    String[] result = replacement.split(" ");
```

- input: `"Hello \n\n\nworld!"`
- replacement: `"Hello \n \n \n world!"`
- result: `["Hello", "\n", "\n", "\n", "world!"]`

Note: my example does not handle the final exclamation mark - but it seems you already know how to handle that.

Comment: I guess that result will be like this: ["Hello", "\n", "\n", "\n", "world!"]

Comment: This is a simple but elegant solution, I can't believe I didn't think of it myself! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Alynchos Don't worry. That is normal: when we write the code, we all get stuck in the details sometimes. But when someone else looks at our code, they have a fresh unopinionated view of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to add whitespace after each "\n" and then apply your regex.

```
    String line = "Hello \n\n\nworld!";
    line = line.replaceAll("\n", "\n "); // here we replace all "\n" to "\n "
    String[] items = line.split(" +|(?=\\p{Punct})|(?<=\\p{Punct})");   

or shorter version:

    String line = "Hello \n\n\nworld!";
    String[] items = line.replaceAll("\n", "\n ").split(" +|(?=\\p{Punct})|(?<=\\p{Punct})");
```

So, in this context the result is: ["Hello", "\n", "\n", "\n", "world", "!"]

Answer (score 0):

Using the find method makes things easier:

```
String str = "Hello \n\n\nworld!";
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\w+|\\H");
Matcher m = pat.matcher(str);

while (m.find()) {
    myList.add(m.group(0));
}
```

If you use Java 7, change `\\H` to `[\\S\\n]`.

Note that using this approach, you obtain a pattern easier to write and to edit since you don't need to use lookarounds.